# Radius of cylinder formed by rotating a square

Tags: geometry

When a square is rotated by side, a cylinder is formed? What is the radius of the cylinder formed? I guess it would be side of the square divided by 2*pi.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the axis of rotation is a side of the square, and so the radius of the cylinder (which is perpendicular to the axis) is the other side of the square i.e. radius = side